# Lagrangian with negative mass

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, gauge-theory, beyond-the-standard-model

I was reading a paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03094 considering the SM extension with $SU(2)$ singlet and doublet fermions. After EWSB, the mass eigenstates are the linear combinations of gauge eigenstates. However, when I tried to diagonalize the mass matrix shown in Eq.7 of this paper, I found that eigenvalues of non-diagonal mass matrix contains negative values. Does it mean that the particle has negative mass? What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign of fermion mass is just a human convention.

Let's say you have a Dirac Lagrangian with positive mass $m$:
$$
L = i\bar{\psi}\not{\partial}\psi - m\bar{\psi}\psi
$$

If you redefine the fermion as
$$
\psi' = i\gamma_5\psi
$$
it can be easily verified that the Dirac Lagrangian turns into:
$$
L = i\bar{\psi'}\not{\partial}\psi' + m\bar{\psi'}\psi'
$$
The mass term changes sign, therefore fermion $\psi'$ has **negative mass** $-m$. Does it change any thing? No, the sign of fermion mass is just a human convention, which usually does not matter.

One caveat: one measurable effect of the sign/phase of the fermion mass is the phase of the strong CP violating topological term. But it is far removed from our usual daily concern.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks a lot!