# Imaginary part of the Dirac Lagrangian density as a total derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

> Show that the imaginary part of the Dirac Lagrangian [*density*] is a total derivative.

**My attempt:**

The Dirac Lagrangian density is given by,
$$ \mathcal{L} \ = \ -\bar{\psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + m)\psi $$
Now, as far as I am aware, the hermiticity conditions of the gamma matrices depend on which representation one uses - we used the Weyl representation in class but with the $(-, +, +, +)$ metric, so there was a factor of $-i$ in every matrix - essentially meaning that the matrices would be anti-hermitian (and therefore, their complex conjugate should furnish a negative sign). Including this is not necessary for my solution, but I will still do it.

The spinors themselves are complex (as far as I know) and all I can say is that the product $\psi^{\dagger}\psi$ should be real.
Thus,
$$ \mathcal{L}^{*} \ = \ -\bar{\psi}^{*}(-\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + m)\psi^{*}. $$
This implies,
$$ \mathcal{L} - \mathcal{L}^{*} = -\bar{\psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + m)\psi - \bar{\psi}^{*}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} - m)\psi^{*}$$
$$ = -\partial_{\mu}(\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi + \bar{\psi}^{*}\gamma^{\mu}\psi^{*}) + (\partial_{\mu}\bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} - m\bar{\psi})\psi + (\partial_{\mu}\bar{\psi}^{*} \gamma^{\mu} + m\bar{\psi}^{*})\psi^{*} .$$
Here, the expressions in the brackets in the second and third terms vanish if I impose the equations derived from Dirac Lagrangian itself. This means,
$$ \frac{1}{2i}(\mathcal{L} - \mathcal{L}^{*}) = \mathrm{Im}(\mathcal{L}) = \partial_{\mu}f^{\mu} $$
This is a total derivative as I am supposed to prove.

**My issues with my solution:**

In order to derive this, I impose the dynamical equations derived from the starting Lagrangian - is it at all valid? The Dirac equation says,
$$ (\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + m)\psi = 0.$$
This clearly says that *if* I impose this equation on the starting density, I get $\mathcal{L} = 0$ - this does not seem to be different from what I have done in my own solution, except that I imposed the equation later instead of at the beginning. The imaginary part being $0$ is of course a valid solution (since any constant field will have a vanishing divergence) but it is a trivial solution.

At the same time, the only other option I see is to use both the idea that the chosen representations of the gamma matrices are anti-hermitian *and* the plane wave solutions of the Dirac field to derive something - but there are similar problems there too (since then I would need to look into all the momentum states, $u(p), \ v(p)$) and the entire procedure would be tedious and I am not even sure if I will get an answer. The second issue to that is that then the proof is not be general - I will have assumed a form of both the matrices and the spinors.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Due to the comments by @MadMax, I feel like I should provide some other information that I skipped (because I felt it was not needed). One of them is the negative sign in front of the Lagrangian that I included in this edit.

In our course, we defined the gamma matrices as,
$$ \gamma^{0} = -i\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\ \gamma^{i} = -i\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma^{i}\\-\sigma^{i}&0\end{pmatrix}$$
The Dirac adjoint was defined as,
$$ \bar{\psi} = i\psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}$$
And the metric, as I mentioned earlier, is $(-,+,+,+)$. Finally, the Lagrangian is defined as,
$$ \mathcal{L} = -\bar{\psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + m)\psi $$

As @MadMax mentions, the mass term would have picked up a factor of $i$, but since our definition of the Dirac adjoint was different, it doesn't.

Comment: For metric $(-, +, +, +)$, instead of $\mathcal{L} \ = \ \bar{\psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + m)\psi$, should your Lagrangian be $\mathcal{L} \ = \ i\bar{\psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} + m)\psi$? 
 Assuming that we are talking about Grassmann-odd $\psi$
 field, there is a missing i, right?

Comment: We didn't have an i in class; but we defined the gamma matrices with an extra factor of i.

Comment: "We didn't have an i in class", then you might consider asking your professor for refund of your tuition :)

Comment: "but we defined the gamma matrices with an extra factor of i", because of this extra i factor in the gamma matrices, the mass term picks up an extra i since $\bar{\psi} = \psi^{\dagger}\gamma_0$ and there is an extra i coming from $\gamma_0$. As for the kinetic term, the extra i from $\gamma_0$ cancels out the extra i from $\gamma_\mu$, therefore it stays the same as the metric (+,-,-,-) format.

Comment: For the Lagrangian, you can take a look at Edward Witten's paper referenced in this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/513768/dirac-equation-without-i/513772#513772

Comment: @MadMax Please refer to the edit I made above - it clarifies some of things related to the conventions we used. Thanks for pointing this out - I never really scrutinised the factors of $i$ or the negatives before. The one thing that bothers me here is the $+m$ in the version of my equation - it seems to be a $-m$ in every reference I check.

Comment: For spinor/fermion, the sign of the mass term does NOT matter, you can pick either positive or negative. It's just a convention. See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/757096/lagrangian-with-negative-mass/765499#765499

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a representation of the Gamma matrices, there exists some matrix $\beta$ which satisfies
$$
(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger = \beta \gamma^\mu \beta^{-1} , \qquad \beta^\dagger = - \beta .
$$
The Dirac conjugate is defined by
$$
{\bar \psi} \equiv i \psi^\dagger \beta . 
$$
Now, let's consider the Dirac Lagrangian,
$$
{\cal L} = {\bar \psi} ( \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu  + m ) \psi
$$
Taking a complex conjugating and manipulating further, we find
\begin{align}
{\cal L}^* &= [ {\bar \psi} ( \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu  + m ) \psi ]^* \\
&= [ i (\psi^\dagger \beta ) ( \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu  + m ) \psi ]^\dagger \\
&= - i \psi^\dagger  ( ( \gamma^\mu )^\dagger \overleftarrow{\partial_\mu}  + m ) (\psi^\dagger \beta )^\dagger \\
&= - i \psi^\dagger  ( \beta \gamma^\mu \beta^{-1}\overleftarrow{\partial_\mu} + m )\beta^\dagger \psi  \\
&= - {\bar \psi} ( \gamma^\mu  \overleftarrow{\partial_\mu} + m ) \psi \\
&= {\bar \psi} ( \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu + m ) \psi - \partial_\mu [  {\bar \psi}   \gamma^\mu  \psi ] \\
&= {\cal L} - \partial_\mu [  {\bar \psi}   \gamma^\mu  \psi ] .
\end{align}

Comment: I understand the steps here - but I don't understand why taking a complex conjugate is akin to taking the Hermitian. Is it because the Lagrangian is a scalar and taking the conjugate transpose just means taking a conjugate? Also, why does there always exist such a matrix like $\beta$? In the usual conventions for the gamma matrices and such, it always seems like the relation holds coincidentally. Thanks!

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. By $- {\bar \psi} ( \gamma^\mu  \overleftarrow{\partial_\mu} + m ) \psi 
= {\bar \psi} ( \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu + m ) \psi - \partial_\mu [  {\bar \psi}   \gamma^\mu  \psi ]$, you changed the sign of the mass term. Please double check your math.